# How to connect to google pubsub using credential json file

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to write a function to publish message to google pubsub, by using json file which has credential details (got from secret manager).

**public async Task PublisMessage(ApiRequestHeaders MetaData, PubSubRequest pubSubModel)
{
string jsonPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");

```
GoogleCredential googleCredential = null;
using (var jsonStream = new FileStream(jsonPath, FileMode.Open,
    FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(jsonStream);
}

var createSettings = new PublisherClient.ClientCreationSettings(credentials: googleCredential.ToChannelCredentials());

TopicName topicName = new TopicName(pubSubModel.ProjectId, pubSubModel.TopicName);
try
{
    
    PublisherClient _publisher = await PublisherClient.CreateAsync(topicName,
    clientCreationSettings: createSettings);
    var _message = await GetPublisMessage(pubSubModel.DocumentId, MetaData);
    var acknowledgmentNumber = await _publisher.PublishAsync(_message); //Permission denied error
    
    return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.Error("PushMessageToPubsub  Error : " + ex);
    return false;
}
```

}**